# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "authentication_author" does not exist: Django v4

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

I tried to start using Postgresql instead of sqlite in my Django project.
I installed postgreqL ON MY Windows, creatred a new database, user and password.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'database_name',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'admin',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

But when I try to migrate or makemigrations, I got this:

> File
> "C:\Users\s...\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
> line 85, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "authentication_author" does
> not exist LINE 1: ...hentication_author"."is_doctor" FROM
> "authentic...

here is my model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="author")
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True,)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And yes, I deleted the sqlite3 database, all the migrations folders and I created new ones with the **init**.py inside of them.

But still get the same problem.

**Updated**
Traceback screenshots:
[image: second-error]

[image: first error]

Comment: Could you add the full traceback and `AuthenticationAuthor` model's code?

Comment: Are you using PGAdmin 4? Did you `python manage.py makemigrations authentication` then migrate? Can you connect to your PSQL database using psql and from a command-line like CMD? If so, can you display databases and tables? Just some thoughts.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak the Author model belongs to the authentication app.

Comment: @Jarad Yes, I can access to the database from the CMD. I tried to makemigrations first, but nothing. That's the only model I have.

Comment: And what about the full traceback? I'm pretty sure that there we'll have an answer.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak I updated the question with some screenshots

Comment: Try to comment out this code (at `notification.signals.py`) and run `makemigrations` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens with Django. Sometimes you can invoke some code that relies on a new DB schema at the time you're trying to `makemigrations`.

All you need in this situation is to temporarily comment out all the code that connects `makemigrations` with your new model's schema. As it was in this question, you can trace related blocks of code just using full traceback.